# jupyter notebook is not showing result but In[*] for each input

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I used jupyter notebook, for unknown reasons, every input line, like In[1], becomes to be In[*] and show no result.

I do not know what to do to solve this problem. Any one can give me some advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it giving you an errors about the Jupyter kernel?

Comment: No error. All the kernel ran well before, but now all breaks. When I use Cell->Run All or execute single kernel, they seem to execute but showing no result and input line symbol all becomes In[*] rather than showing the numbers.

Comment: Anaconda distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is the anaconda distribution for python

Comment: Try reinstalling distribution?

Answer (score 0):

If the code in one of the cells is still running and doesn't complete (e.g., infinite loop), then that cell is marked by In[*] and all other cells will return In[*] if run. Stop the code that won't complete and rerun the other cells.